# Database Project, Baseless Merge with SSDT & TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

How do we best perform a Baseless Merge between two branches of a TFS Database Project?
We have a change in Branch B that we need to merge into branch A. Can we make a Schema Compare in VS and just update?

Comment: Not as familiar with TFS as we use Git, but merging into a branch has generally been painless by choosing to merge B into A. However if this is a single change you could easily do a schema compare against a DB with that change or just copy/paste the change into branch A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a baseless merge just like you would regardless of the type of files that are in your branch (it has nothing to do with the fact that you are using Database Projects, they are treated the same way as any other type of project - just a bunch of files in a branch).

In the Merge dialog it will list in the drop-downs the branches that have relationships, but you can always browse for another target branch to initiate a baseless merge.

[image]

Comment: Or if it's no available to browse to (that depends on your Visual studio version), you can always initiate the merge from the commandline using `tf merge $/ProjectA/BranchA $/ProjectA/BranchB /recursive /baseless`